# Flutter / Android Emulator / VSCode pasting to clipboard

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I randomly get messages at the bottom of my Android Emulator while hitting restart on VSCode for my app. They read:

*MyApp pasted from your clipboard*

("MyApp" being the name I gave my app)

Sometimes it just pops up once. Sometimes is pops up multiple times in a somewhat rapid progression. It just started happening out of nowhere.

Steps to resovle:

- I thought it might be the code I was adding (adding validators on textformfields) so I reverted those, but that didn't help.
- I closed VS Code and the emulator and restarted.
- I restarted my Macbook Pro.

It doesn't happen every time and it doesn't seem to be impacting the app most times. Once however, it happened several times and then crashed the app on the emulator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it happen even after  using `flutter clean` ? And yes sometimes I find issue on hot-restart, and it is ok I think (might be)because of cache system. Then I do hot-restart or rebuild the app, and some implements 'assets, some packages' need to use restart/rebuild.

Comment: I tried `flutter clean`, same issue still occurs.

Comment: 10 days later...the issue occurs less frequently, but still randomly occurs. No resolution.